# How to used same code in helper data in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, phtml, helper, front

Here is my object manager code can any one guide me how can i used same code in my helper data

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customOptions = $objectManager
                       ->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
                       ->getProductOptionCollection($_product);
$custom_option_data = $customOptions->getData();
```

and call in phtml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    protected $productOption;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $productOption
    ) {
        $this->productOption = $productOption;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function FunctionName($_product)
    {
        return $this->productOption->getProductOptionCollection($_product)->getData();
    }
}
```

Totally Agree with @Diana Botean.

Might this help you.

Comment: Thanks, buddy but please pay attention to @Diana Botean post/answer too.

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, **you should not use Object Manager**, this is a bad practice and its direct usage reduces dependency visibility and prevents type validations and hinting.

Secondly, **you should not use helper classes to load any data** as it is a bad practice as well.

<strike>Instead, **your code should adhere to the MVVM pattern**, please read more on the topic in https://weblizar.com/blog/magento-2-is-model-view-view-model-system-and-not-mvc-explained/:</strike>

> The Magento block object serves as a ViewModel if you speak
> specifically about the MVVM system. The object block is capable of
> scanning and reading the business models, user requests, acquiring
> data from external system, etc. the template file is termed as View
> that solely collaborates with the block object that is the View Model.

---

**LE** if you don't go with the MVVM approach due to version usage (which was pointed to me in the comments - thanks @paj), I suggest you add the code inside a model class, which you can call from a block class associated to your phtml (similar to what you would have implemented in m1).

[image]

Comment: Hi @Diana Botean, I have a different story to say. I have also read that we should you ViewModel as its server for single use but I was facing an issue with VM when I have enabled FPC. I have not idea why the same code was working on without FPC and not on FCP but then I have to remove VM and use a helper and everything comes to its place. Can you guide me on this. and also why paid extensions don't use Use VM in place of Helper? Thanks, This question only for seeking knowledge don't take it in another way. Thanks Again

Comment: View models are available in Magento 2.2 onwards. OP states M2.1 in tags.

Comment: fair enough, even so, it is still indicated not to use helper classes to load data and neither is using object manager usage. i updated my answer on the topic :) thanks @paj for pointing the version detail!